# SOQL Query on CollaborationGroup returns zero rows within Platform Event Trigger transaction context

Tags: apex, trigger, community, platform-event

I am publishing a platform event to post chatter in a chatter group from the guest users. When I run the below query in the dev console then it returns a record. When I use hard code Id then I am able to post chatter.

```
Query:  select Id, Name from CollaborationGroup where Name ='ABC Group';
```

Method in platform event trigger:

```
public static void postToChatter(List<Post_To_Chatter_Event__e> listChatter) {
        List<FeedItem> listPosts = new List<FeedItem>();
         List<CollaborationGroup> chatterGroup = [select Id, Name from 
         CollaborationGroup where Name ='ABC Group'];
        // System.debug(' chatterGroup '+chatterGroup);
        
        for (Post_To_Chatter_Event__e chatter : listChatter){
            FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
            post.Title = chatter.Title__c;
            
            post.Body = chatter.Body__c;
            post.ParentId = chatterGroup[0].Id;
            post.LinkUrl = chatter.LinkUrl__c;
            listPosts.add(post);
        }
        
        
        if (listPosts.size() > 0) {
            insert listPosts;
        }
    }
```

But when I run the same query in the platform event trigger then it returns 0 records. Can anyone help is there any limitation or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

You are likely running into this - [Apex Platform Event Triggers executes as 'Automated Process' user](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000317184&type=1&mode=1).

The key parts from that help article are:

> When an Apex-trigger is configured as the subscriber of a platform event, **the trigger executes as 'Automated Process' instead of the causing user** (the user who created the platform event).

and

> In some cases SOQL queries executed in the context of the Automated Process user may not return expected results.

You see the expected results in developer console anonymous Apex because it is running as your user. And your user can access that `CollaborationGroup`.

I did find the idea [Give the "Automated Process" User an actual admin profile](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003aTkQAI) with the comment:

> Automated Process is also not able to Get records of Collaboration Groups in Scheduled Flow. Please give Automated Process an Admin Profile.

Voting for that idea should help in the long term.

A comment on that idea pointed out a new Spring '21 feature: [Configure the User and Batch Size for Your Platform Event Trigger](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_messaging_trigger_config.htm&type=5&release=230). You could try using the `PlatformEventSubscriberConfig` metadata records to define a specific user for the trigger to run as.

Comment: thank you for the response. But on idea someone replied that “This issue might have been indirectly solved in the Spring '21 release”.

Comment: @VinitMehta That is a good point about the Spring `21 release. If you configure the Platform Event trigger to run as a specific user you could gain access to the `CollaborationGroup` records.